# C# not calculating

Tags: c#

```
double cash;
private void btnHesapla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int number= Convert.ToInt32(tbadet.Text);
    int oneprice= Convert.ToInt32(tbbirim.Text);
    cash= number * oneprice;


    if (number >= 100)
    {
        double i = 0;
        i =cash- (cash * (5 / 100));
        lblcash.Text = cash.ToString() + " $" + (" Discount");
    }else
    lblcash.Text = cash.ToString() + " $";
}
```

If the customer is over 100, they will get 5% off
but without a discount calculate

Comment: You are calculating `i` and not using it.

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Comment: Question is unclear. What are you trying to do? What is the problem? What have you done to try and solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign final result to `i` variable but you use cash variable to show result.

Also, as **@Bathsheba** said `(5 / 100)` results to `0` because this operation uses two integers.

Replace this line:

```
i = cash - (cash * (5 / 100));
```

by this:

```
cash -= cash * 5 / 100;
```

You should assign to `cash` variable.

Comment: or `cash -= cash * 5 / 100;`, cause (5/100) would be always 0.

Comment: @SeM, thank, edited

Answer (score 0):

5 / 100 is an expression equal to 0 due to integer division.

Removing the parentheses will fix this one, and don't forget to assign to cash, rather than i which you can remove.

cash *= 0.95 is probably clearer.